# Localize control using code

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I need some examples to understand how localize controls like MessageDialog. I'm able to localize xaml controls using x:Uid and Resources.resw file but I don't understand how to do it using C#

Answer (score 0):

Use a ResourceLoader:

```
 ResourceLoader resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse("Resources");
```

and for getting the strings:

```
string localizedstring =  resourceLoader.GetString("string1");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Visual Studio says me to use ResourceLoader.GetCurrentView() method. Whe I try to use ResourceLoader.GetCurrentView("App name/Resources "); I receive an error: ResourceMap not found! Why?

Comment: Are your resources in a Resources folder, and your strings in folders for each language?

Comment: I resolved the first problem. Can I use this technique with the file created by Microsoft  Multilanguage toolkit?